# Add GeoJson file to the Folium.Express.Choropleth ( ) function

Tags: geojson

**fig=px.choropleth(data_frame=new_df, geojson= 'Louisville_GeoJson', lat='Latitude', lon='Longitude', color='NumberKilled', animation_frame='Date', center={'lat':38.328732,'lon':-85.764771})**

the above is the code.   I want to add a geojson file in the px.choropleth ( ) function.   The geojson file is the geojson file of a city named Louisville ( Kentucky , USA) This file is the city boundary.

The above code will generate a map showing number of death killed in raod accident each day from 2018-2022.